# Selecting maximum value in JSON data type

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I'm working with Kairos responses and I have that one:

```
{
   "images":[
      {
         "file":"foo.jpg",
         "faces":[
            {
               "yaw":1,
               "roll":1,
               "pitch":-8,
               "width":113,
               "height":113,
               "face_id":1,
               "quality":0.13918,
               "chinTipX":107,
               "chinTipY":215,
               "topLeftX":52,
               "topLeftY":95,
               "attributes":{
                  "age":31,
                  "lips":"Together",
                  "asian":0.00125,
                  "black":0.0001,
                  "other":0.00571,
                  "white":0.98087,
                  "gender":{
                     "type":"M",
                     "maleConfidence":0.99999,
                     "femaleConfidence":0.00001
                  },
                  "glasses":"None",
                  "hispanic":0.01207
               },
               "confidence":0.99946,
               "eyeDistance":48,
               "leftEyeCenterX":133,
               "leftEyeCenterY":126,
               "rightEyeCenterX":85,
               "rightEyeCenterY":125
            }
         ],
         "width":214,
         "height":317,
         "status":"Complete"
      }
   ]
}
```

I can select the small portion of this json with this query:

```
select facedata.data->'images'->0->'faces'->0->'attributes' 
from facedata 
where facedata.data->'Errors' isnull;
```

But I want to need just five key of this small portion; **black**, **white**, **hispanic**, **asian** and **other** in order to be able to find the maximum value of these keys.

How can I select multiple keys of a JSON and find the maximum value?

Comment: please add the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Do you search for the maximal value in one photo? Then try this using `json_each()`.

```
SELECT each.key::text,
       each.value::text::decimal
       FROM facedata
            CROSS JOIN json_each(facedata.data->'images'->0->'faces'->0->'attributes') each
       WHERE facedata.data->'Errors' isnull
             AND each.key IN ('black',
                              'white',
                              'hispanic',
                              'asian',
                              'other')
             AND each.value::text::decimal = (SELECT max(eachi.value::text::decimal)
                                                     FROM json_each(facedata.data->'images'->0->'faces'->0->'attributes') eachi
                                                     WHERE eachi.key IN ('black',
                                                                         'white',
                                                                         'hispanic',
                                                                         'asian',
                                                                         'other'));
```

(Note: It will find ties if there are any. You might need to tweak it, if you don't want that.)

Or for the maximum of the values in several photos? Then you might like to try this.

```
SELECT max((facedata.data->'images'->0->'faces'->0->'attributes'->'black')::text::decimal) black,
       max((facedata.data->'images'->0->'faces'->0->'attributes'->'white')::text::decimal),
       max((facedata.data->'images'->0->'faces'->0->'attributes'->'hispanic')::text::decimal),
       max((facedata.data->'images'->0->'faces'->0->'attributes'->'asian')::text::decimal),
       max((facedata.data->'images'->0->'faces'->0->'attributes'->'other')::text::decimal)
       FROM facedata
       WHERE facedata.data->'Errors' isnull;
```